# How to extract random element from an array - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, random

I am doing a project in *JS* and *Node.js* and I need to extract a random element from my array and then display it.

```js
// enemies.js
const enemies = [
  "Wizard Monster",
  "Ice Golem",
  "Electro Dragon",
  "Fire Giant",
  "Rahzar Mutant",
]
export default enemies

// fight.js
import enemies from "../utils/enemies.js"

// Code here
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the specific issue? Have you generated a random 0 <= number < enemies.length? If not, how to do so is searchable, e.g., "javascript generate random number between..." etc.

Comment: Have you at least tried: `enemies[Math.floor(Math.random() * enemies.length)]`?

Comment: "Any ideas?" isn't a suitable question here. Please revise to describe exactly what you're having trouble with. I see no code that would display a value. See [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like below will give you a random element from the array:

```
let enemy = enemies[Math.floor(Math.random()* enemies.length)];
```

Using underscore or lodash is another option:

```
let enemy = _.sample(enemies);
```

or

```
let enemy = enemies[_.random(enemies.length-1)];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const enemies = [
  "Wizard Monster",
  "Ice Golem",
  "Electro Dragon",
  "Fire Giant",
  "Rahzar Mutant",
];
const amount_items_array = enemies.length;
const item_sorted = Math.floor(Math.random() * amount_items_array);
enemies.splice(item_sorted, 1)
console.log(enemies);
```

Comment: That's... an approach. Seems a bit heavy for the task, and I don't understand why something is called `_sorted` since there's no sorting, or what the intermediate length variable is really useful for.